# Python/CGI isn't interpreted

Tags: python, cgi

I'm currently trying an example from the "Real Python For the Web" book where you get started with CGI and Python.

But somehow the browser won't compile the python code.

Here's the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env/ python
print "Content-Type: text/html"
print
print """
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello, World!</h2>
</body>
</html>
"""
```

but when i access the file via localhost it only displays uninterpreted (/plain) text of the whole script - instead of showing only the "Hello, World"

I already tried:
- which python --> to get the shebang directory
- file has the 755 permission
- compile the script in python without a webserver

Comment: Did you put the script in a directory that allows CGI execution?

Comment: Also, "env" is a command.

Comment: what do you mean with CGI execution?

Comment: CGI scripts are executed by the server. In order to reduce security issues, a web server will only allow execution of CGI scripts in specific directories.

Comment: If that book hasn't explained this, then it's no good. Actually, it's no good anyway: "Real Python" on the web isn't done by means of CGI.

Comment: You should also replace `/usr/bin/env/` with `/usr/bin/env` in the first line of the script.

Comment: @ daniel - the book is actually quite nice! and they only use CGI to show the logic behind webdev!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys! The Problem was that I executed the 
    python -m CGIHTTPServer 8000
command out of the cgi-bin folder instead of the next higher direction and that I made a backslash too much at #!/usr/bin/env !